# Lock yourself out of your phone for a certain amount of time

Tags: productivity

I check my phone (Android) more than I study. Is there any program or way to lock yourself out of your phone for a certain amount of time until you complete a goal? At the same time it should allow phone calls to come through.

Answer (score 1):

Hand it to a roommate?  Or trade phones with a study partner?

Reminds me of the old "how do I stop myself from using my credit cards" scenario:

http://moneyning.com/credit-cards/freeze-your-credit-cards-to-ice-your-spending/

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of apps that allow this in each their way:

- [App blocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.mobilesoft.appblock) - Let's you set up daily intervals between 1 to 3 hours where your phone is blocked from usage. I believe you can set it up to allow calls.
- [Stay Focused](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stayfocused) - Which let's you block individual apps, either on set intervals during the day or by allowing a total usage time per day for apps.

Hope these covers your question.